# Point of types in Elastic 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch

ES newbie here, simple question: What is the point of a type in ES 6.x if each index can only have one type? I've noticed that inserting a document requires both the type and index to be specified, but this seems redundant to me.

Comment: Did you look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html ? Elastic removed mapping types and provided an explanation. Mapping type in general specifies the type of data an index/ document contains.

Comment: I am more questioning the redundant nature of the type field. Why isn't it removed altogether? Is there a use for it?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html:

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or later may only contain a
>   single mapping type. Indices created in 5.x with multiple mapping
>   types will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x.
>   Mapping types will be completely removed in Elasticsearch 7.0.0.

and:

> ### Why are mapping types being removed?
>
> Initially, we spoke about an “index” being similar to a “database” in
>   an SQL database, and a “type” being equivalent to a “table”.
>
> This was a bad analogy that led to incorrect assumptions. In an SQL
>   database, tables are independent of each other. The columns in one
>   table have no bearing on columns with the same name in another table.
>   This is not the case for fields in a mapping type.
>
> In an Elasticsearch index, fields that have the same name in different
>   mapping types are backed by the same Lucene field internally. In other
>   words, using the example above, the `user_name` field in the `user` type
>   is stored in exactly the same field as the `user_name` field in the
>   `tweet` type, and both `user_name` fields must have the same mapping
>   (definition) in both types.
>
> This can lead to frustration when, for example, you want `deleted` to be
>   a `date` field in one type and a `boolean` field in another type in the
>   same index.
>
> On top of that, storing different entities that have few or no fields
>   in common in the same index leads to sparse data and interferes with
>   Lucene’s ability to compress documents efficiently.
>
> For these reasons, we have decided to remove the concept of mapping
>   types from Elasticsearch.

More details you can find under the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html).